# How to code this alertcondition in prine script

Tags: alert, pine-script

I have two separate indicators,
EMA1 is a ema and EMA2 is a wma.

I would like the same alert condition for both indicators
for example alertcondition(EMA1 = open or high or low or close or EMA2 =  open or high or low or close)

This alert will highlight the candles that use the Ema or the Wma as support or resistance. I want a alert if the Ema price or the Wma price is equal to anyone of theses 4 variables.

This is how I syntax the code in pine script
alertcondition(EMA1 = open or high or low or close, title= "LowRiskEntryEma", message= "LowRiskEntryEma signal detecded" or EMA2 = open or high or low or close, title= "LowRiskEntryWma", message= "LowRiskEntryWma signal detecded")

I keep getting this error probably because my syntax is wrong
line 22: Mismatched input '=' expecting ')'.

Is there a simpler way to syntax this alert condition

Im not a progammer so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show what you have written so far, so people know you don't want them to write your code instead of you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to  code an alarm it is already  present in tradingview  . You simply have to to wre the condition in message box of  alarm . You not know about ot just go and read manual of alert in tradingview  . I my opinion   your all don't will be resolved.  Just read alarm  manual
carefully . If you not able to find  it got to  find  help center >alarm > read about message.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).